# Print Array List

Tags: javascript, html, arraylist, hyperlink

I am very new to web development and am trying to create a  website that will allow the user to input their favorite website links and then print these links below the text box. After the link is printed, it has to be clickable for the user. However the problem I am running into is that my program will not allow the user to input multiple links, it simply updates the first input.

```js
var urlList = [];

function saveUrl(){
    var site = {url};
    
    var i = 0;  
    var favSite = ""; 
    
    site.url = document.getElementById('url').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    
    urlList.push(site);
    
    for(i =0; i<urlList.length;i++){
        
        var thisSite = {url}; 
        thisSite = urlList[i];
        
        lnk.href = "http://" + thisSite.url;
        favSite = lnk.href;
        favSite+="<br>";
    }
    
    lnk.innerHTML = favSite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

    <title>Favorites</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="attempt4.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    
        <form>
        
            <input type = "text" id = "url" size = "25">
            <input type = "submit" value = "submit" onclick="saveUrl();return false">
        
        </form>
    
        <a target="_blank" href="" id=lnk></a> <br>    
           
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to store them in an array? Just add the new link to a list directly.

Comment: Change `lnk.innerHTML = favSite;` to `lnk.innerHTML += favSite;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to save the links to an array and then reprint that array each time the user enter a link. Just add the new link to the list like this:

```js
function addLink() {
  var lnk = document.getElementById("lnk").value; // get the input value
  
  var a = document.createElement("a");   // create a new anchor element
  a.href = "http://" + lnk;              // set its href
  a.textContent = lnk;                   // set its text content
  
  var li = document.createElement("li"); // create a new list item
  li.appendChild(a);                     // add the anchor element to it
  
  var ul = document.getElementById("links"); // get the ul element
  ul.appendChild(li);                    // add the list item to it
}
```

```html
<input id="lnk"/>
<button onclick="addLink()">ADD</button>
<h3>Your Links:</h3>
<ul id="links">
<ul>
```

Comment: Wow this makes a lot more sense and is much cleaner than the route I was taking. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
favSite = lnk.href;
```

It must be:

```
favSite += lnk.href;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `lnk.innerHTML = favSite;` to `lnk.innerHTML += favSite;` so that instead of setting the HTML to an entirely new value (and throwing away the old one), you append the new link onto the HTML that was already there.

```js
var urlList = [];

function saveUrl(){
    var site = {url};
    
    var i = 0;  
    var favSite = ""; 
    
    site.url = document.getElementById('url').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    
    
    
    urlList.push(site);
    
    for(i =0; i<urlList.length;i++){
        
        var thisSite = {url}; 
        thisSite = urlList[i];
        
        lnk.href = "http://" + thisSite.url;
        favSite = lnk.href;
        favSite+="<br>";
    }
    
    lnk.innerHTML += favSite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Favorites</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="attempt4.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    
    <form>
        
        <input type = "text" id = "url" size = "25">
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit" onclick="saveUrl();return false">
        
        </form>
    
    <a target="_blank" href="" id=lnk></a> <br>    
        
    
        
    </body>    
</html>
```